# Very frequent bibtex question

Tags: discussion, specific-question

A question appearing very frequently is "I have created a `bib` file, but my  references don't appear in the pdf" and variations, where the cause is the failure to run the usual 
`latex->bibtex->latex->latex` workflow.  In general a comment about the workflow suffices. Thus, it seems to me that all of them should be closed as duplicate, and in general they do not add to the general knowledge.

So, my question is what would be the best way to handle such questions. Shall we provide a comment and propose to close them, mark as duplicate (and in this case do we  have a standard question/answer we refer to?)

Comment: usually it's best to find an existing clear question and decide that is the reference question and mark others as duplicates, or if no clear question is found just ask it as cw and answer it with a canonical answer at same time. Not looked if there is a good question/answer existing already

Comment: You might look at [Bibliographies](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/2428/15717) section in the well organised [Often referenced questions](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2419/15717) at meta.tex.sx

Answer (score 13, accepted):

We have a number of these questions already on the site.  I think the most comprehensive answer is this question:

- [Question mark or bold citation key instead of citation number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/2693)

So the best solution is to vote to close using this as the duplicate.

Comment: Indeed the answer is really good and comprehensive.